# how to declare dynamic JS variables for a PHP page

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I'd like advice on the best way to include dynamic js variables.  There are certain js variables which come from the server, similar to:

```
var user_preferences = [<?php //declare some type of array here;?>];
```

Obviously, you can't run PHP in a *.js file (though I suppose you could with Apache and a .htaccess directive), and besides I believe you don't want dynamic content in a *.js file because the whole idea is for the browser to cache the code.

The total set of these variables (such as AJAX url locations, user settings) is actually pretty small.  I really would prefer not to declare them all on a page, but instead include them somewhere, but how would I do that given that they are dynamic?

Comment: You *can* run PHP in a javascript file. You just have to know what yuou're doing. Google it.

Comment: Instead of creating a js file create a php file say config.php and use <script> tag to declare your variables. (as explained by Mehul below)

You can include this php file where ever you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guys in comments said, you can run php in js files, just rename it.

Example of JS file, named generated_data.php:

```
function pero( miki ) {
  miki.innerHTML = "<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>";
  console.log("ext");
}
```

now, let us add this to html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="generated_data.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>

<script>
  pero( document.getElementById("test") );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like this approach.  I have not seen it used much but probably haven't noticed it.  Any example of larger sites that use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. All this in one file

```
<?php

$someCoolVar = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
// ...
?>

//.....
<script>
var myVar1 = <?=$someCoolVar;?>; // myVar1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
// ...
</script>
```